# Getting Invalid digit, Value '_', Pos 2, Type: Integer while running select query

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

all I have an external spectrum table in redshift and it contains almost 600 columns when I try to run SELECT query for the spectrum table it is giving me an error "Invalid digit, Value '_', Pos 2, Type: Integer" I don't know how to solve it. If anyone have any idea please command me.

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM spectrum_table;
OUTPUT: Invalid digit, Value '_', Pos 2, Type: Integer
```

Comment: Does `SELECT * FROM spectrum_table LIMIT 10` work instead?

Comment: What is your data format? If it's CSV it's likely that due to quoting/escaping issues in the file some values are treated as being different columns. What's your external table DDL (mostly the quoting, and escaping settings)?